# Invalid result from coderbyte

Tags: java, algorithm, testing

Refer to the test below, some test cases are failed in fact even the output is correct. Can anyone advise?

https://coderbyte.com/editor/Longest%20Word:Java

**Longest Word**
Have the function LongestWord(sen) take the sen parameter being passed and return the largest word in the string. If there are two or more words that are the same length, return the first word from the string with that length. Ignore punctuation and assume sen will not be empty.
**Examples**

Input: "fun&!! time"

Output: time

Input: "I love dogs"

Output: love

Below are the invalid failing test cases

1. For input "a beautiful sentence^&!" the output was incorrect. The correct output is beautiful
2. For input "oxford press" the output was incorrect. The correct output is oxford
3. For input "123456789 98765432" the output was incorrect. The correct output is 123456789
4. For input "a b c dee" the output was incorrect. The correct output is dee
5. For input "a confusing /:sentence:/[ this is not!!!!!!!~" the output was incorrect. The correct output is confusing

The program

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {

    public static final String REG_EXP_CHAR_ONLY = "(?=.*?[a-zA-Z0-9 ])";

    public static String LongestWord(String sen) {

        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (String c : sen.split("")) {
            //System.out.println("c--------->" + c);
            if (isValid(c)) {

                strBuffer.append(c);

            }
        }

        //System.out.println(strBuffer.toString());
        String longest = Arrays.stream(strBuffer.toString().split(" ")).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                .orElse(null);

        return longest;
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String c) {
        // System.out.println("char -->" + c);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REG_EXP_CHAR_ONLY);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(c);
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        if (matchFound) {
            // System.out.println("Match found");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(LongestWord(s.nextLine())); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a problem from coderbyte. I copied your code and submitted. Then it passed.[image]

==================================================================
Edit:
maybe you should use "StringBuilder"(not StringBuffer) instead.
I just fixed all warnings in ide and then all tests pass.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {

    public static final String REG_EXP_CHAR_ONLY = "(?=.*?[a-zA-Z0-9 ])";

    public static String LongestWord(String sen) {

        StringBuilder strBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        for (String c : sen.split("")) {
            //System.out.println("c--------->" + c);
            if (isValid(c)) {

                strBuffer.append(c);

            }
        }
        
        return Arrays.stream(strBuffer.toString().split(" ")).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String c) {
        // System.out.println("char -->" + c);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REG_EXP_CHAR_ONLY);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(c);
        // System.out.println("Match found");
        return matcher.find();
    }

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(LongestWord(s.nextLine())); 
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: @Nanthan Drake you only have 1 point but my submission is 2 points. check out whether the result has any incorrect test cases

Comment: @BananaTech I just passed tests using new code

Comment: StringBuffer doesn't cause the test cases mentioned above failed. It's quite clear that coderbyte has some issue..